# How to set input cloud for pcl::BoxClipper3D

Tags: c++, point-cloud-library

My pcl version is 1.8.
I plan to use pcl::BoxClipper3D to remove the points inside a box.As there is an angle between the box and the x-axis of point cloud, pcl::cropbox cannot used directly.So I choose pcl::BoxClipper3D.
However there is no member method to set input cloud because it not inherit from Filter.
So anyone have idea to use pcl::Boxclipper3D to filter points inside a certain box?